# Project doesn't run after adMob update

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I have updated my old project with new adMob id and it wanted me to update the SDK version because it doesn't support iOS 8. So I have updated it via pod update and now I get the error when building: [image]

Search paths:
[image]
[image]
[image]

What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Have you removed the old version of AdMob from your project and Search Paths?

Comment: Yes, I have deleted old files and removed the search path.

Comment: I have created a new project and moved everything to it. And it's ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new project and copy all the code to it. It's worked.